# How to correctly get the second row of a partition by

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

First of all, I'm using BigQuery. In my table I have some duplicated rows due to a change in one of the columns (called fmid). When this happens, I have to get the latest record, which is defined by the time (called created_date). The only thing these duplicated records have in common is the id (called tid).

I have tried two different options to set which row is the first and which one is the latest, so then I could remove what I want.

**First one:**

```
SELECT *, row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY tid) as number

FROM (SELECT created_date,tid, fmid

FROM table 

ORDER BY tid,created_date)

ORDER BY tid, created_date
```

Results:
Sometimes it's correct, but the order of the id 296644550 is not right.

```
1   2023-02-03 22:11:07 UTC 233330088   4   1
2   2023-02-04 10:07:06 UTC 233330088   18  2
3   2023-02-11 11:06:42 UTC 284447799   4   1
4   2023-02-11 11:22:13 UTC 284447799   18  2
5   2023-02-10 10:39:23 UTC 296644550   4   2
6   2023-02-10 19:32:08 UTC 296644550   18  1
```

**Second one:**

```
SELECT *, row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY tid,created_date) as number

FROM (SELECT created_date,tid, fmid

FROM table 

ORDER BY tid,created_date)

ORDER BY tid, created_date
```

Results:
The column "number" gets the same result.

```
Row created_date    tid fmid    number
1   2023-02-03 22:11:07 UTC 233330088   4   1
2   2023-02-04 10:07:06 UTC 233330088   18  1
3   2023-02-11 11:06:42 UTC 284447799   4   1
4   2023-02-11 11:22:13 UTC 284447799   18  1
5   2023-02-10 10:39:23 UTC 296644550   4   1
6   2023-02-10 19:32:08 UTC 296644550   18  1
```

Any idea of what's wrong?

Comment: Please can you edit your question and show us some simple data and the expected output as text not image ? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,for%20users%20with%20visual%20impairments.

Comment: You need to add the order createtome to the window of rownumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the sorting has to happen in the window of row_number, so that you get the correct number

```
SELECT created_date,tid, fmid
FROM (SELECT created_date,tid, fmid
      , row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY tid ORDER BY created_date) as number
       FROM table 
)
WHERE number = 2
ORDER BY tid
```

or as CTE

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT created_date,tid, fmid
      , row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY tid ORDER BY created_date) as number
       FROM table )

SELECT created_date,tid, fmid
FROM CTE
WHERE number = 2
ORDER BY tid
```